# Separate login view in a Durandal App

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

**DOM** for my Durandal app is structured as below:

```html
  //shell.html
  <div id="applicationContentWrapper" >
    <!-- ko compose: {model: 'viewmodels/header', activate:true} --> <!-- /ko -->
    <div data-bind="router:{}"></div>
  </div>
```

Here's a snippet of my router configuration

```javascript
router.map([
        { route: '', moduleId: 'viewmodels/dashboard', name: 'dashboard'},
        { route: 'form', moduleId: 'viewmodels/form', name: 'form'},
        { route: 'login', moduleId: 'viewmodels/login', name: 'login'}
]);
```

As you can see my login view gets inserted into the `<div data-bind="router:{}"></div>` which is the expected behaviour. But if I am on the **login** view I need to hide the **header** view which I have managed to do by subscribing to the router configuration in the header viewmodel:

```javascript
router.activeInstruction.subscribe(function (val) {
    val.config.name === "login" ? showHeader(false) : showHeader(true);
});
```

But this feels a little messy and the **DOM** for the **header** view is still in the page, what I really want to do is if I am in the in the **login** view I just want the **DOM** for the login view to be there as if I am in separate page with only the **login** view. But so far I have not found a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. The ultimate responsibility for security is NEVER in your front-end. Everything you 'close off' on the front-end can easily be accessed by a malicious user. The back-end should secure all your functionality and data, the front-end only hides it to give the user a better experience. So in other words, it doesn't matter that it's still in the DOM (from a security standpoint). Even if it wasn't, it wouldn't be more secure.
2. If you want to not have the nodes in the DOM anyway (for performance reasons), use the `with` or `if`-binding. They hide whatever's inside if the condition is falsy.
3. The subscription on activeInstruction is indeed a bit messy. You need to improve your logic. The header isn't hidden because the user is on the login page, the header is hidden because the user ISN'T LOGGED IN. That is a BIG difference. What you are doing is essentially a dirty hack. Have an observable/computed observable in your shell viewmodel (or somewhere else) that returns whether the user is authenticated. Then based on that, show/hide your header.
4. Using the authenticated-observable I mentioned above, you can also 'guard' your views by checking against this observable. That way you can make sure a user can't navigate to routes for which he needs to be authenticated. Again though, the ultimate responsibility for this security-check is on your backend, not your frontend.

### Edit

I can understand your reasoning for wanting a whole different 'layout' without the rest of the DOM for your login view. But this goes against the whole idea of a single-page application. It is also unnecessary. A bit of smart css and data-binding (visible, if, with) will give you the same results, often providing a better user experience than a full page reload would do. If you insist on breaking the SPA though, place a router one level lower: e.g. the main router only knows a login route and an internal route. The internal route has another router which holds all the other pages. This way you can move the common HTML from your shell view to the internal view.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. The header is presentation specific so from a security point of view I am happy. The problem I was having was that there was a flicker when initially rendering the logon page. But I understand what you mean by doing stuff with visible and if binding and subscribing to check if the user is logged in or not to display the header. I will give that a try. Mean while I will keep the question open just in case some one else has done it differently.

Comment: Looks like I just needed to get the logic right and the everything falls into place. Thanks!!